# Select N Row with DB2 in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, db2

I want to get the first 95 data from DB2 in Visual Studio. I'm using table adapter and I have this query,

> SELECT        * FROM            ASEINDTA.TRX_BWS WHERE        (DKLDATE
>   = '2019-10-31') Fetch First 95 Rows Only

or this

> SELECT        * FROM            ASEINDTA.TRX_BWS WHERE        (DKLDATE
>   = '2019-10-31') ORDER BY Col[ 1 ]...Col[ n ]
>   Fetch First 95 Rows Only

But when I click Query Builder, this error appears.
[image: image error]

But when I tried it in DBVisualizer, it works. How do I get that data? A help would be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Your query really needs to have an `ORDER BY` clause to make asking for the "first" 95 rows to make sense.  Which column(s) are you using for ordering?

Comment: do this `SELECT TOP(95) [col1], [col2], [col3] FROM ASEINDTA.TRX_BWS WHERE DKLDATE like '%2019-10-31'% order by col1 desc`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hello, I've tried `ORDER BY` before but didnt mention it, and not work eiter.

Comment: Edit your question to show the c# code. Don't use dbms specific syntax in the query (fetch first...). You can use the arguments to the table-adapter/DataAdapter fill method to limit the result-set. You can also do the limiting at the dbms end by encapsulating the query in a routine.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would work on DB2 and most other databases would be to use `ROW_NUMBER` with a subquery:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_col) rn
    FROM ASEINDTA.TRX_BWS
    WHERE DKLDATE = '2019-10-31'
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 95;
```

Or, the inlined version that does not use CTE:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_col) rn
    FROM ASEINDTA.TRX_BWS
    WHERE DKLDATE = '2019-10-31'
) t
WHERE rn <= 95;
```

Comment: Umm, its table adapter in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Syafiqur__ Then use the inlined version, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: Nope. Cant use that query.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parentheses of the where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM ASEINDTA.TRX_BWS WHERE DKLDATE = '2019-10-31' Fetch First 95 Rows Only
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is not on db2-server it-self, but from the tool you are using to execute the queries. You said, if you run the same in 'DBVisualizer' it works properly.

Looking at db2 documentation for this error:  [sqlcode -104  sqlstate 42601](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0104n)

it seems this error is returned by SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD stored procedure. 
This procedure is designed to run db2 administration commands in the target database, remotely. It was not designed to run queries...  so, the parser for this proc is just a sub-set of db2 parser, just for specific admin commands. 
So it's complaining about the FETCH token from your query.

It seems that the tool you are using  **'I'm using table adapter'** (no idea on what is it) , is calling this SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD to execute the queries, but it should be using a regular CLI interface instead.

I don't know what exactly tool you are using.  but try to see if it has some sort of settings,  so you can change that behavior.

Here is the list of admin cmds that ADMIN_CMD proc can execute: 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0012547.html .

as you can see,  no SELECT statement there.

If I try to execute a simple SELECT , using this SP,  I get the same error,  from db2 CLP window, directly at the server.

```
db2 "call SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT')"
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "SELECT" was found following
"BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "ADD".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Regards
Samuel Pizarro

Answer (score 0):

Ok
I had a closer look at the image error you posted...

the query is wrong.  It's not exactly the same queries you posted in your question.

Have a closer look at the image error, and you will see that the Fetch and Rows words are  double-quoted.

```
SELECT ... FROM WHERE (...) "Fetch" First 95 "Rows" Only
```

Remove the double-quotes from them.

If you are not writing them like that, so,  it looks your tool is "changing" it, before submitting to the db2 engine.  Again,  not a db2 server issue.

Regards

Comment: Hello, as soon as I click the `Query Builder` button, the double quote appeared. I try remove at first, and it still appeared in my query. What do you mean by my tool is changing it?

Comment: I mean exactly what you are describing.
The quotes should not be there for this token (FETCH),  its part of the syntax.  Its not a named identifier. 
It looks that "Query Builder" is not designed to work with other DBMS syntax,  and its expecting MSSQL syntax only.   
Do you need to use "query builder" ?   It seems its not recognizing the keyword, and its treating it as it was a column alias, and putting the double quotes around it.

Comment: Yes I need, to check the query and the expected result

Comment: normally,  "Query builders" are only tools to assist you to build your SELECT statements..   Executing them and check the expected results can be done without them.